# SSL connection to Tomcat (behind Apache - mod_jk)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, mod-jk

The SSL connection is working for every page on the Apache server except these served to Tomcat. Tomcat works well on http connection.

**The setup:**

- Apache/2.2.21
- Tomcat-7.0.23
- mod_jk to connect them
- self-signed certificate

**What is working**

If I try to connect to tomcat through http everything is OK. Every page which is specified in the JkMount directive is forward to Tomcat and all the others pages are Apache's responsibility. I have two virtual hosts - one for port 80 and one for 443. The working configuration for 80 is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *******

JkMount /cas ajp13_worker
JkMount /cas/* ajp13_worker

</VirtualHost>
```

**What is my problem**

When I try to use https with similar vhost configuration for port 443 - there is an entry in the apache logs:

```
File does not exist: ****/apache2/htdocs/cas
```

**Configuration files**

The settings for vhost on port 443:

```
<VirtualHost ****:443>
ServerName *******

JkMount /cas ajp13_worker
JkMount /cas/* ajp13_worker

</VirtualHost>
```

In the httpd.conf the section for mod_jk is:

```
JkWorkersFile ****/tomcat-7.0.23/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile ****/apache2/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

(I've read that I need the following lines ... )
JkExtractSSL On
JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS
JkSESSIONIndicator SSL_SESSION_ID
JkCIPHERIndicator SSL_CIPHER
JkCERTSIndicator SSL_CLIENT_CERT
```

In httpd-ssl.conf I've specified the certificate paths ... https is working correctly for all pages except the Tomcat ones.

DocumentRoot is specified in httpd.conf.

**Questions**

What is controlling whether the Apache is searching in DocumentRoot dir or forwarding the requests to Tomcat? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: What's the output from `apache2ctl -S`?  I have a sneaking suspicion that a different :443 vhost is getting the requests instead.

Comment: Could you write this as an answer (so I can select it) and not just a comment. This was my problem. There was a second vhost for 443 in `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of `apache2ctl -S` - a second SSL vhost that is loading first on the port will get requests instead of the desired vhost.

Answer (score 1):

> What is controlling whether the Apache is searching in DocumentRoot
>   dir or forwarding the requests to Tomcat?

Two factors: the order and definition of `<Directory>` and related directives, and the `JKMount` location(s).

I am curious why you think you need two - just use /cas/* (apache will redirect a request for /cas to /cas/ automatically if /cas does not exist, based on the DirectorySlash setting, which defaults to On)

Comment: I've read some examples and just enter it like that. You are right - I need only '/cas/*'.

Answer (score 1):

The `DocumentRoot` from the **httpd.conf** is only in charge for the global Apache settings. If you set on your server on a `VirtualHost`configuration it shouldn't interfere with your VH at all.

I'd recommend for now to increase your`LogLevel`and check the log file after that. Additionally, if it ain't on productive server yet, you can drop the `DocumentRoot` lines in httpd.conf as well.

I haven't used **mod_jk** for a very long time as I find the configuration itself not very amusing. I switched over to **mod_proxy** for this sort of reverse proxying as it is more intuitive. In case of Tomcat I use **mod_proxy_ajp** and enclose the elements with the `<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>` container. But that might be a personal flavour thing. If you can't figure out why, you might save time giving that a try.

Comment: I have tried mod_proxy_ajp - it seems easier to configure. When I add `ProxyPass /cas ajp://localhost:8010/cas` to the vhost configs: if I add it to to *:80 config section - it works (like with mod_jk) ... but when I add it to the 443 section - all requests are forward to the htdocs dir. There is no helpful info in the logs (I've switched to debug). Any ideas?

Comment: How does your `<VirtualHost>`container for SSL look like? Can you try and work with the IP address? Like `<VirtualHost 222.333.444.555:443>`and do you have the `NameVirtualHost` set for SSL as well?